# Best way to deinit Initial view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios10

I have a loading view controller when my app starts(is is my initial view controller).When an animation in this view controller finished I want it to show another view controller and dismiss the view controller with the animation.

The loading view controller is the initial view controller,

I have this code when UIStoryboard.mflMainTabBarViewController(). returns the view controller that I want to present

```
func animationDidStop(_ anim: CAAnimation, finished flag: Bool) {
    let animationID = anim.value(forKey: "animationID")
    if animationID as! NSString == "transform" {
        self.present(UIStoryboard.mflMainTabBarViewController(), animated: true, completion: {
            _ = self.popoverPresentationController
        })

    }
}
```

But when deinit is never called

```
deinit {
print("deinit")
```

}
What is the best way to deinit the first view controller, and making the presenting view controller the root view controller?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're doing something very specialized, you don't need to de-init an object in Swift. It will be called automatically when the reference count goes to 0. If you really need to, you should be able to set you window's `rootViewController` through your `AppDelegate`.

However, be aware that maintenance like this is rarely necessary.

Comment: I just wanna make sure that the loading view controller did go

Comment: The completion block (where you have `_ = self.popoverPresentationController`) will be called when the presentation is complete. is the ViewController not showing up?

Comment: Yes the view controller is showing, but the deinit func is not called in the debugger

Comment: It won't be called because your Window still has a reference to it as the rootViewController ( and possibly other places, I can't see all of your code). Why do you need de-init to be called?

Answer (score 0):

A deinitializer is called immediately before a class instance is deallocated

after you can use

```
    if let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate {

        let storyboard : UIStoryboard? = UIStoryboard(name: "storyboardName", bundle: nil)
        let rootController = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "controllerIdentifier")

        delegate.window?.rootViewController = rootController
    }
```

Comment: is there a smooth way to do this?

Comment: loading controller can call dismiss method and you can add the code above in the completion method. if you need de init you can add code as well.