# Controller doesn't deinit after present new controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have a `FakeSplashController` which does some network requests and after that open `WelcomeViewController`. When I look memory graph in `WelcomeViewController`, I see that `SplashViewController` is still in there. I'm calling `deinit` function in `FakeSplashController` to check If It is deniniting but It doesn't call it. What can be the problem?

What I see in Memory when in `WelcomeViewController`:
[image]

**FakeSplashController:**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    setupUI()
    networkRequests()

}

func networkRequests(){

    AppInitService().initAppRequest { [](result) in
        switch result{
        case .success(_):
            self.startAnimation()
            return
        case .error(let error):
            UIControlUtil.showErrorMessage(title: error.title, message: error.message, closeButton: true)
            return
        }
    }
}

func openApp(){
        let loginController = WelcomeViewController()
    self.present(loginController, animated: true)
}

func startAnimation(){
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.8, animations: {
        self.logoImage.frame.origin.x -= 100
    }, completion: nil)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1,delay: 0.3,animations: {
        self.textLogo.alpha = 1
        self.textLogo.frame.origin.x += 50
    }, completion: { _ in
        self.openApp()
    })
}

deinit {
    print("Splash Deinited")
}
```

EDIT: As I red in below post, someone mentioned that;

> Unless you're doing something very specialized, you don't need to de-init an object in Swift. It will be called automatically when the reference count goes to 0. If you really need to, you should be able to set you window's rootViewController through your AppDelegate.

So don't I need to take this as a problem?
[Best way to deinit Initial view controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45601121/best-way-to-deinit-initial-view-controller)

Comment: How do you  expect splash screen to be deallocated since you present `WelcomeViewController` ?

Comment: I think I'm not sure If it needs to be. Since I dont have anything to do with splash anymore.

Comment: A view controller is not deallocated when you present another one; it still lives under new one. In fact, if you dismiss `WelcomeViewController` you'll see the splash again

Comment: @RicoCrescenzio is right, you can also see that, when you open the ViewDebugger of Xcode. Scroll a little to the sides in the ViewDebugger you will see, that behind your WelcomeViewController is the SplashViewController. When you would dismiss the WelcomeViewController, you would see the SplashViewController as well.

Answer (score 3):

As I said in the comment, there's nothing strange in your code, it's how the iOS framework works; the view controller is not deallocated because it's still the `rootViewController` of the current window.
I don't think it's very needed to deallocate it, but if you really need to do it, a solution could be to replace the `rootViewController` with your `WelcomeViewController`. By replacing it, the reference count of the splash screen will go to 0 and it will be deallocated. 
Something like

```
guard let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow else {
    return
}
self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
window.rootViewController = WelcomeViewController()
```

The problem of this is that there's no animation (but you can achieve the animation too, just find how to animate `rootViewController` change)

Comment: Just one more question. For example I have a ViewController which store 10mb on memory. When I didn't deallocate it (like doing in my code), It will still use 10 mb on memory or will be deallocated?. I'm not sure which one I do need to use for splashController

Comment: It will be alive, so it will keep using 10 mb until its reference count reaches 0.

Comment: So It is better to use your code for SplashViewController and even WelcomeViewController cuz It will not be seen till user logout?

Comment: Maybe it’s better in terms of memory usage, but I would not worry about 2 simple view controllers; then I would have to re-implement the push animation to make the navigation consistent

Comment: Hmm maybe you will be true. One solution is to keep it and other one is to make a custom animation for push? It would be great If there is more Information about keeping vs deiniting it.

Comment: You could create a reusable way to animate every view controller change and it will be used for both situations

Comment: I could try your solution now but still I can see splashViewController in memory. Why It can be?

Comment: Try to dismiss your current viewcontroller before change the root one...